# multiple object creation on a single API call on django

Tags: django-rest-framework

i have to create multiple object creation on a single API call.My
 serializer class is like this

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    dt = datetime.now()
    strg = '{:%d%m%Y%H%M%S}'.format(dt, dt.microsecond // 1000)
    hat= "REQ" + strg
    creater = dot_order_models.DotOrder(reqnum=hat,**validated_data)
    creater.save()
    return creater
class Meta:
    model = dot_order_models.DotOrder
    fields = ('merchant', 'biker','batch','customer_name','contact','city','locality','order_amount')
```

i just given `many=true` but did not work. then i give

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    many = kwargs.pop('many', True)
    super(BikerSerializer, self).__init__(many=many, *args, **kwargs)
```

this too didn't work.how can i solve it using serializers and view class.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data, many=isinstance(request.data, list))
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    self.perform_create(serializer)
    results = dot_order_models.DotOrder.objects.all()
    output_serializer = dot_order_serializers.DotOrderSerializer(results, many=True)
    return super(DotOrderViewSet, self).create(request)
```